# How to measure word co occurence frequency

Tags: nlp

How is frequency defined in word co occurrences?

Is it the number of times the two words appear together/ total number of documents in corpus

OR

the number of times the two words appear together / (number of times first word appears + number of times second word appears)?

Comment: depending on your needs you can calculate it differently, I've used to calculate it as `number of times two words appear together / number of first word appears`

Answer (score 0):

"The GloVe model is trained on the non-zero entries of a global word-word co-occurrence matrix, which tabulates how frequently words co-occur with one another in a given corpus." - from https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ (GloVe publishers). 
I'm assuming you're referring to co-occurrence as used by GloVe models. Mathematically: 
https://towardsdatascience.com/emnlp-what-is-glove-part-ii-9e5ad227ee0
You have P(i|j) = Xij/Xi w/ Xij = Number of Co-occurances, and Xi = Number of times any word appears in the context of word i. Note Xi = Sum_k Xik where k is every word.